# Azure Data Factory - Google BigQuery Copy Data activity not returning nested column names

Tags: azure, google-bigquery, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have a copy activity in Azure Data Factory with a Google BigQuery source.
I need to import the whole table (which contains nested fields - Records in BigQuery).

Nested fields get imported as follows (a string containing only data values):

`"{\"v\":{\"f\":[{\"v\":\"1\"},{\"v\":\"1\"},{\"v\":\"1\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"1\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"1\"},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":null},{\"v\":\"0\"}]}}"`

Expected output would be something like:

`{"nestedColName" : [{"subNestedColName": 1}, {"subNestedColName": 1}, {"subNestedColName": 1}, {"subNestedColName": null}, ...] }`

I think this is a connector issue from Data Factory's side but am not sure how to proceed.
Have considered using Databricks to import data from GBQ directly and then saving the DataFrame to sink.
Have also considered querying for a subset of columns and using `UNNEST` where required but would rather not do this as Parquet handles both Array and Map types.

Anyone encountered this before / what did you do?

Comment: FYI, there is a request for MSFT to support this, which you can vote on: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/5499da03-3d6b-ed11-a81b-000d3ae5ae95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution used:**

Databricks (Spark) connector for Google BigQuery:

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/google/bigquery.html

This preserves schemas and nested field names.

Answer (score 1):

Preferring the simpler setup of ADF BigQuery connector to Databricks's BigQuery support, I opted for a solution where I extract the data in JSON and 'massage' it into Parquet using Databricks:

1. Use a Copy activity to get data from BigQuery with all the data packed into a single JSON string field. Output format can be Parquet or JSON (I'm using Parquet). Use a BigQuery query like this:

```sql
select TO_JSON_STRING(t) as value from `<your BigQuery table>` as t
```

**NOTE:** The name of the field must be `value`. The `df.write.text()` text file writer writes the contents of `value` column into each row of the text file, which is a JSON string in this case.

2. Run a Databrick notebook activity with code like this:

```py
# Read data and write it out as text file to get the JSON. (Compression is optional).
dfInput=spark.read.parquet(inputpath)
dfInput.write.mode("overwrite").option("compression","gzip").text(tmppath)

# Read back as JSON to extract the correct schema.
dfTemp=spark.read.json(tmppath)
dfTemp.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(outputpath)
```

3. Use the output as is, or use a Copy activity to copy it to where you like.